# Shorthand for conditional statements

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, if-statement

I am looking for a way to write something like this:

```
if (product.Category.PCATID != 10 && product.Category.PCATID != 11 && product.Category.PCATID != 16) {   }
```

In a shorthand way like below, which does not work of course:

```
if (product.Category.PCATID != 10 | 11 | 16) {   }
```

So is there shorthand way at all to do something similar ?

Comment: It's been answered in this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c/33384#33384

Comment: @LaserBeak: Your latest edit changes your question **COMPLETELY**! This doesn't even compile.

Comment: @LaserBeak: It is very bad practice to change your question substantially after answers have been posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an extension method:

```
    public static bool In<T>(this T source, params T[] list)
    {
        return list.Contains(source);
    }
```

And call it like:

```
  if (!product.Category.PCATID.In(10, 11, 16)) {  }
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes - you should use a set:

```
private static readonly HashSet<int> FooCategoryIds
    = new HashSet<int> { 10, 11, 16 };

...

if (!FooCategoryIds.Contains(product.Category.PCATID))
{
}
```

You can use a list or an array or basically any collection, of course - and for small sets of IDs it won't matter which you use... but I would personally use a `HashSet` to show that I really am only interested in the "set-ness", not the ordering.

Comment: For more info and uses of the HashSet, look here. http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2009/12/22/c-hashsett/

Answer (score 3):

not exactly a shortcut, but maybe the right thing for you.

```
var list = new List<int> { 10, 11, 16 };
if(!list.Contains(product.Category.PCATID))
{
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well... I think a shorthand version would be `if(true)`, because if `PCATID` == 10, it is != 11 and != 16, so the whole expression is `true`.
The same goes for `PCATID == 11` and for `PCATID == 16`.
And for any other number all three conditions are `true`.
==> You expression will always be `true`.

The other answers are only valid, if you really meant this:

```
if (product.Category.PCATID != 10 && 
    product.Category.PCATID != 11 && 
    product.Category.PCATID != 16) {   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like that:

```
List<int> PCATIDCorrectValues = new List<int> {10, 11, 16};

if (!PCATIDCorrectValues.Contains(product.Category.PCATID)) {
    // Blah blah
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!new int[] { 10, 11, 16 }.Contains(product.Category.PCATID))
{
}
```

Add `using System.Linq` to the top of your class or `.Contains` generates a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple with `switch`:

```
switch(product.Category.PCATID) {
    case 10:
    case 11:
    case 16: {
        // Do nothing here
        break;
    }
    default: {
        // Do your stuff here if !=10, !=11, and !=16
        //    free as you like
    }
}
```